# Many error messages after update from EE5 to EE6.4.6

Tags: error, update

I am seeing many error messages post-update from EE 5.x.x to EE 6.4.6. They go away if I revert back to PHP 7.4 from PHP 8.1. All add-ons (just Wygwam and ChannelImages) are up to date. Dreamhost server. Any suggestions greatly appreciated (previous list of error messages removed for clarity).

UPDATE:
Thanks eeharbor for supplying the new ChannelImages update (7.5.2) this made the error messages I was seeing when saving an entry go away. However, I still am seeing the following error messages on multiple sites that I updated from EE version 5.x.x to 6.4.6, with PHP version set to 8.1:::

```
WHEN LOADING CERTAIN PAGES ON FRONT END:

Deprecated
ctype_digit(): Argument of type bool will be interpreted as string in the future
ee/ExpressionEngine/Addons/channel/mod.channel.php, line 4187
Severity: E_DEPRECATED

Warning
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at ee/legacy/core/Exceptions.php:120)
ee/ExpressionEngine/Boot/boot.common.php, line 475
Severity: E_WARNING

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
WHEN TRYING TO DOWNLOAD TEMPLATES (OPERATION FAILS COMPLETELY):

Deprecated
ZipArchive::open(): Using empty file as ZipArchive is deprecated
ee/ExpressionEngine/Controller/Design/AbstractDesign.php, line 331
Severity: E_DEPRECATED

Warning
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at ee/legacy/core/Exceptions.php:120)
ee/legacy/helpers/download_helper.php, line 54
Severity: E_WARNING
```

Answer (score 1):

A new release of Channel Images: 7.5.2 has been released to fix this. Thank you for your patience as we update our addons to php 8.2

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem arising in the Channel Images add-on - see the lines

```
Deprecated
parse_str(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated

user/addons/channel_images/api.channel_images.php, line 596

    Severity: E_DEPRECATED

Deprecated
parse_str(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated

user/addons/channel_images/api.channel_images.php, line 596

    Severity: E_DEPRECATED
```

It looks like these issues then trigger a cascade of other issues.

Channel Images claims to be php 8.2 compatible in the latest version ([7.5.1](https://eeharbor.com/channel-images/changelog)) - so if this error is happening and that's the version you are using I think you should get in touch with eeharbor to see if they can resolve it for you.

HTH.

Comment: Still seeing error messages after updating ChannelImages to 7.5.2. I have listed them in an update to my original post above. The errors appear on some front end pages and when trying to download templates in the backend.

Comment: EE6 is not yet fully php 8.2 compatible - I imagine those errors will go away when it gets update to fix - right now the only version of EE that works properly with php 8.2 is EE7.

Comment: What about PHP 8.1? That is what I have been testing with. Is EE 6.4.2 not fully compatible with 8.1?

Comment: I just ran a new test. With EE 6.4.2 running on PHP 8.0 (NOT 8.1 or 8.2). I am still seeing the error messages shown in my OP when attempting to perform the download templates function under Templates in EE. Our hosting service (Dreamhost) has been sending notices out saying that PHP 7.4 (the only lower version of PHP available there) is no longer supported. Is EE 6.4.2 really not fully compatible with any version of PHP 8.x?

Comment: EE 6.4.2 should be compatible with php 8.1 and php 8.0 - I don't have a copy to hand to test though. If it is not working for you then I would suggest as a first step updating the site to 6.4.6 (which certainly is compatible with both) - you can do this easily via the "1 click" updater in EE control panel. If your issue persists after that I suggest you post an issue at the EE github (at https://github.com/ExpressionEngine/ExpressionEngine/issues).

Comment: Sorry, "6.4.2" was a typo - I have updated multiple sites to 6.4.6 and consistently see that the templates download function fails and yields a series of error messages (shown in my original post above). The issue only occurs in conjunction with any version of PHP 8.x and goes away if I set PHP back to 7.4. Have I found a bug?

Comment: I just tried updating EE to 6.4.7 - no help.

Comment: Well as noted previously I suggest you file a bug report with the EE github. Perhaps there is something odd about your system that is triggering the errors that could be useful for the developers to know.